# Shifting along the range of histogram values

Tags: matlab, histogram, shift

Say that I have some `image`, for which I found the `histogram`. Say also that I have some `equation` that I want to calculate for each element in the histogram. How can I shift along the histogram values in `MATLAB`?

I have done the following:

```
I=imread('xyz.jpg');
h=imhist(I);
h(1) % get the value of the first element
```

In this way, to apply my equation, I used `h(1)` value for instance.

Is that right this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate the histogram values, I suggest that you extract both outputs of `imhist` (I took the liberty to give them more expressive variable names):

```
[counts, bins] = imhist(I);
```

Arrays `bins` and `counts` contain the histogram bin locations and their counts, respectively. Then you can use a for loop:

```
res = zeros(numel(counts), 1); %// Preallocate array for the result
for k = 1:numel(counts)
    %// Apply equation on counts(k) and bins(k), for example:
    res(k) = some_equation(bins(k), counts(k));
end
```

or apply the equation in a vectorized form, if possible.